# How to add and delete items in an array from inside a child view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, uiviewcontroller

Let's say I declare an NSMutableArray in the class file foo.h. Then in the viewDidLoad method in foo.m I populate the array. Inside foo.m I can add, delete, or modify array elements.

Then let's say the following code executes inside foo.m

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:bar animated:YES];
```

This will switch the view and program execution will continue inside bar.m. How can I do all the things to the array in bar.m that I was able to do in foo.m?

Comment: What do you mean by *modify the array*?

Comment: Add, delete, or modify items.

Comment: Ordinarily, you'd want to do that in the view controller that's presenting the array, typically by allowing the user to edit a table view. Is there a reason you need that responsibility to be shared across two view controller instances?

Comment: I have an array of student objects. Each object has several attributes such as a name, id, and other details. Initially, only the name of each student is displayed in a list. When the user clicks on a name, the view will switch which will provide a screen that has all the student's details. The user should be able to edit these details.

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to do it. The second view controller should also import the class that foo imports. Right before pushing the second view controller, set that class object equivalent to the object that the user selected. Any changes to that object will occur to the same object in the array.

When you go back to the table view though you won't see the changes unless you reload the table. That's a different story though.